# aadhar auth XML validation with XSD

Tags: xml, authentication, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am trying to validate the sample Auth XML with XSD which is provided by aadhar developer portal but getting error:

```
Type 'http://www.uidai.gov.in/authentication/common/types/1.0:uid' is not declared, or is not a simple type)
```

but in auth XML I have specified `uid` element .

Auth XML :

```
<Auth xmlns="http://www.uidai.gov.in/authentication/uid-ath-request/1.0" ac="public" lk="MBFWjkJHNF-fLidl8oOHtUwgL5p1ZjDbWrqsMEVEJLVEDpnlNj_CZTg" sa="public" tid="public" uid="999991260711" ver="1.6" txn="AuthDemoClient:public:20160701120821">
<Uses pi="y" pa="n" pfa="n" bio="n" pin="n" otp="n" />
 <Meta udc="UIDAI:SampleClient" fdc="NA" idc="NA" pip="127.0.0.1" lot="P" lov="110002" />
<Skey ci="20200916"></Skey>
<Data type="X"></Data>
<Hmac></Hmac>
</Auth>
```

auth XSD :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.uidai.gov.in/authentication/uid-auth-request/1.0"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.uidai.gov.in/authentication/uid-auth-request/1.0"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:ar="http://www.uidai.gov.in/authentication/uid-auth-request-data/1.0"
    xmlns:common="http://www.uidai.gov.in/authentication/common/types/1.0">

    <xs:import namespace="http://www.uidai.gov.in/authentication/common/types/1.0"
        schemaLocation="common-types.xsd" />

    <xs:simpleType name="TknType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="001">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Mobile number</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="TknValue">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="100"></xs:maxLength>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:complexType name="Tkn">
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="tns:TknType"></xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="value" type="tns:TknValue"></xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>


    <xs:simpleType name="UsesFlag">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="y"></xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="n"></xs:enumeration>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:complexType name="Uses">
        <xs:attribute name="pi" use="required" type="tns:UsesFlag" />
        <xs:attribute name="pa" use="required" type="tns:UsesFlag" />
        <xs:attribute name="pfa" use="required" type="tns:UsesFlag" />
        <xs:attribute name="bio" use="required" type="tns:UsesFlag" />
        <xs:attribute name="bt" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:attribute name="pin" use="required" type="tns:UsesFlag" />
        <xs:attribute name="otp" use="required" type="tns:UsesFlag" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="Skey">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:base64Binary">
                <xs:attribute name="ci" type="xs:string">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>
                            Certificate identifier - should be expiry date of certificate in YYYYMMDD format
                        </xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:attribute>
                <xs:attribute name="ki" type="xs:string" use="optional">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>
                            Unique key identifier
                        </xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:attribute>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>


    <xs:simpleType name="DataType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="X"></xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="P"></xs:enumeration>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:complexType name="Auth">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Tkn" type="tns:Tkn" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="Uses" type="tns:Uses" />
            <xs:element name="Meta" type="common:Meta" />
            <xs:element name="Skey" type="tns:Skey" />
            <xs:element name="Data" >
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                        <xs:extension base="xs:base64Binary">
                            <xs:attribute name="type" type="tns:DataType" default="X" />
                        </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Hmac" type="xs:base64Binary" />
        </xs:sequence>

        <xs:attribute name="uid" type="common:uid" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="ac" type="common:AuaCode" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="tid" type="common:Tid" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="ver" type="common:Ver" />
        <xs:attribute name="txn" type="common:Txn" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="lk" type="common:LicenseKey" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="sa" type="common:AuaCode" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="Auth" type="tns:Auth"></xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

common-types.xsd

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.uidai.gov.in/authentication/common/types/1.0"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.uidai.gov.in/authentication/common/types/1.0"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:simpleType name="uid">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="\d{12}"></xs:pattern>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="pin">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="\d{6}"></xs:pattern>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="otp">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="\d{6}"></xs:pattern>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="LicenseKey">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="200"></xs:maxLength>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>


    <xs:simpleType name="Tid">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9\.,-\\/():]*"></xs:pattern>
            <xs:maxLength value="50"></xs:maxLength>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="Ver">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9\.,-\\/():]*"></xs:pattern>
            <xs:maxLength value="10"></xs:maxLength>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="Txn">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9\.,-\\/():]*"></xs:pattern>
            <xs:maxLength value="50"></xs:maxLength>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="AuaCode">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9]*"></xs:pattern>
            <xs:maxLength value="10"></xs:maxLength>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="Geocode">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="100"></xs:maxLength>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="Latitude">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="100"></xs:maxLength>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="Longitude">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="100"></xs:maxLength>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="LocationType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string"> 
            <xs:enumeration value="G"></xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="P"></xs:enumeration> 
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:complexType name="Meta">
        <xs:attribute name="udc"  use="required">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:maxLength value="20"></xs:maxLength>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="pip"  use="required">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:maxLength value="60"></xs:maxLength>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="fdc"  use="required">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:maxLength value="10"></xs:maxLength>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="idc"  use="required">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:maxLength value="10"></xs:maxLength>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="lot" type="tns:LocationType" use="required">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>Location Type</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>                
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="lov" use="required">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:maxLength value="50"></xs:maxLength>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="FingerPosition">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>
                    Finger positions
                </xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:enumeration value="LEFT_INDEX"></xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="LEFT_LITTLE"></xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="LEFT_MIDDLE"></xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="LEFT_RING"></xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="LEFT_THUMB"></xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="RIGHT_INDEX"></xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="RIGHT_LITTLE"></xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="RIGHT_MIDDLE"></xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="RIGHT_RING"></xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="RIGHT_THUMB"></xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="UNKNOWN"></xs:enumeration>   
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>


</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Hi Promod are there any sample or test aadhar numbers which I can use during development. Can you please guide ?

Answer (score 4):

In your XML file, there is a single character typo in the namespace declaration that's very hard to notice.

To fix it, change

```
<Auth xmlns="http://www.uidai.gov.in/authentication/uid-ath-request/1.0"
```

to

```
<Auth xmlns="http://www.uidai.gov.in/authentication/uid-auth-request/1.0"
```

and then your XML will validate as expected.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.